# Hotelling model of spatial with 3 players

Tags: game-theory

Three players will open new shops in a linear city denoted by the [0,5] interval. There is no existing shop in the city. Players can locate their shops on integer values, so that they each have 6 potential locations: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}. There can be multiple shops in one location. Player 1 chooses his/her shop location first. Observing this action, Player 2 chooses later. And then, observing those previous actions, Player 3 chooses the last. Players aim to maximize the number of customers they will serve.

The products to be sold in the shops will be identical, and their prices will be equal as well, so the only thing a potential customer cares about is the distance from his/her house to the shop. In particular, a customer shops from the closest shop. If a customer’s house is exactly in between multiple shops, he/she will choose either one with equal probabilities. All customers are discrete-uniformly distributed along the linear city, for the sake of argument, assume that there are 60 customers in each 1-unit distance, e.g., between 0-1, between 1-2, etc.

Example: If Player 1 has a shop in location 1 and the other players both have shops in location 4, here is the number of customers they serve. All 60 customers in the [0,1] interval shop from Player 1; all 60 customers in the [1, 2] interval shop from Player 1; customers in the [2, 3] interval can go to either shop with equal probabilities, so each player gains 20 customers from here; customers in the [3, 4] interval can go to either Player 2’s or Player 3’s shop with equal probabilities, so each Player i ∈ {2, 3} gains 30 customers from here; and customers in the [4, 5] interval behave the same as those in the [3, 4] interval. As a result, Player 1 has a total of 140 customers, and Players 2 and 3 have a total of 80 customers each

Comment: It seems to me that the last (third) player will always want to place its shop anywhere in the largest (most profitable) of the three subsegments (original segment is divided in three parts by the first two shops). Can you try to find how the second player can play optimally, if that is the optimal strategy for the last (third) player? Finally, when how would the first player play if he now knew the optimal strategies of the second and third player? $-$ Notice that there are only $6^3=216$ possible game endings, hence you can even brute force all and the optimal outcomes for all players.